# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS flickering and flashing on/off problem

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, screen, wayland, flicker

Hi I have an issue with my laptop. At first I reboot for some reason and the ubuntu login screen didn't show up. Then I have to change the display manager to `light-dm`. It was `gdm3` and it was working perfectly but suddenly it did not started automatically. Then I started to use `light-dm`. But the screen is constantly flickering. I am using ASUS-x551c with the information that I will provide below. I tried something like using Ubuntu on Wayland but it decreased not ended. I also use a second monitor but even if I don't use it, it have still same issues.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [1043:145d]
    Kernel driver in use: i915

GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
```

I really need help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I tried something like using Ubuntu on Wayland but it decreased not ended"

Comment: I started to use Ubuntu on Wayland by choosing on login screen. It is better now, there is less flickering. But flickering and flashing not completely are ended